# Catch All URLs Ending with GUID

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building an API in .Net Core 2.1 and have a paging system where by the user can request large volumes that returns in chunks of configurable size. When a chunk is sent it will contain a GUID which is the reference to the next chunk of data

For example if we have a hit that returns 526 results, it will chunk the data into 5 x 100 and 1 x 26 record chunks, The first hit comes from
GET /events/

The second page of data will come from something like
GET /events/95d9f018-bff9-46e7-ad86-9b9d6734cc0d

I already have a number of routes on each of my controller methods

```
[HttpGet("/events/"]
public ActionResult GetAllEvents() {}

[HttpGet("/events/{EventId}"]
public ActionResult GetEvent(int EventId) {}

[HttpGet("/events/after/{AfterDate}"]
public ActionResult GetEventsAfter(DateTime AfterDate) {}
```

and in some cases methods can have several route values. What I'd like to add is a single catch all, where if the URL ends with a GUID it is routed differently.

What I am seeing at the moment is that if I append a GUID, it goes into the "GetEvent" method

I have tried adding a route in the MVC

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Continuation",
        template: "Route/{*ContinuationToken}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Continuation", action = "GetPagedResponse" },
        constraints: new { ContinuationToken = @"(?im)^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$" }
    );
});
```

But clearly this is not the correct implementation approach as the request is still routed to the original controller and action, and not the ContinuationController

Is there a way to route all requests that end with a Guid to a particular 
controller and action?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

In the Controller that you want the continuation token to be passed add this snippet,

```
        [Route("/continuation/{continuationToken:guid}")]
        public IActionResult nextResult(Guid continuationToken)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And in your Startup.cs I have this, something similar to your example.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "guidroute",
                    template: "{controller}/{*guid:guid}",
                    defaults : new { controller = "continuation"}
                     );
```

and that gets added before the default route.